# Ruby string replace without capture group

Tags: ruby, string, replace

Ruby's `String.sub(pat, txt)` family of functions performs substitution and supports capturing groups in `txt` even if `pat` is a plain string (at least it seems to support `\0` to print all of `pat` in the replaced text). I don't know if this is intended, but is unsafe if `txt` is e.g. a variable taken as input from an API. Is there an alternative library function I can use to perform string replace without this drawback? Or alternatively some way to escape `txt`.

Comment: Do you have an example of the problem you're having?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "...supports capturing groups in `txt` even if `pat` is a plain string...". Presumably you mean `pat` is a string (how does that differ from a "plain string"?) as opposed to a regular expression. While regular expressions may have capturing groups I don't understand what you mean by strings having them.

Comment: Minor note, but an important one. `String.sub` is a method called directly on `String`, but `String#sub` is one called on an *instance* of `String` which is what you mean here.

Comment: If it's a Rails app (even if it's not!) you can use ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper#sanitize, either as-is or with options mitigating particular vulnerabilities in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this:

```rb
>> "mytext".sub("text", " \\0 replaced by \\` \\0")
=> "my text replaced by my text"
```

You can escape backslashes:

```
>> "mytext".sub("text", " \\\\0 replaced")
=> "my \\0 replaced"

def b_esc(str) = str.gsub("\\", "\\\\\\\\")

>> "mytext".sub("text", b_esc(" \\0 replaced"))
=> "my \\0 replaced"

# how many backslashes?
>> "\\0".chars        #=> ["\\", "0"] # uhh.. yes
>> "\\0".bytes        #=> [92, 48]
#                      one ^ 
>> b_esc("\\0").bytes #=> [92, 92, 48]
#                      two ^   ^
```

Or use a block:

```rb
>> "mytext".sub("text") { " \\0 replaced" }
=> "my \\0 replaced"
```

Or maybe [`[]=`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/string#method-i-5B-5D-3D):

```rb
>> t = "mytext"
=> "mytext"
>> t["text"] = " \\0 replaced"
=> " \\0 replaced"
>> t
=> "my \\0 replaced"
```

---

> Note that within the string replacement, a character combination such as `$&` is treated as ordinary text, and not as a special match variable. However, you may refer to some special match variables using these combinations:
>
> `\&` and `\0` correspond to `$&`, which contains the complete matched text.
> `\'` corresponds to `$'`, which contains string after match.
> `` \` `` corresponds to `` $` ``, which contains string before match.
> `\+` corresponds to `$+`, which contains last capture group.

*https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/String.html#class-String-label-Substitution+Methods*

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with `index` + `insert` in my case since the word always ended with the pattern. `[]=` was the solution I was looking for if this weren't the case.

```rb
def prepend(txt, pat, word)
  index = txt.index(pat)
  return if index.nil?

  txt.insert(index, word)
  true
end
```